# Implement hashCode and equals method but class is final

Tags: java, azureservicebus

There is a class [Message](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/dev/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/Message.java) and it doesn't have `hashCode` and `equals` implementations. So I *wanted* to extend it and implement my own `hashCode` and `equals` method. Alas! This class is final. Is there a technique/hack/workaround that I can use to do this?

I want to avoid adding duplicated to Set. This is the reason.

Comment: i don't understand how implementing these methods helps you if you're adding to a `List`.  A `List` does not care about duplicate objects.  Do you mean that you are adding `Message` objects to a `Set`?  That would make more sense. - If you are adding to a `List`, then you don't need to implement anything new for the `Message` class.  Rather, you need to have external code that checks for duplicates before adding to the `List`.  That code would use the same logic that you'd be putting in your `equals` method if you subclassed Message and let a `Set` do the work for you.

Comment: @Steve, yes you are right. But my situation is a little different. For me, I just want to detect a duplicate and break out of for loop. So Set/List are same for me just for this minor case in point.

Comment: ...not that @Ferrybig doesn't provide a good answer if you really need Message-like objects that implement equals() and hashCode().

Comment: I think this makes my point then.  If you just need to break out of a loop, why do you need to put the "these objects are equal" logic inside the Message object itself.  Why not just figure it out by querying the information in the Message object and doing the comparison right there, in your loop, with that information?

Comment: @Steve, yes. this is easier. I will do this instead. Thanks Steve.

Comment: The title of your question is still a good question in its own right with a good answer to go with it.  So I'm happy with the answer provided.  I'm also happy I could save you some work.

Comment: Don't know what you mean about upvoting my answer, since I didn't provide one, but I'm happy to upvote your question...it's a good one.

Comment: @Steve, **I've managed to break the shackles of the Java language, and now do a lot of my new programming in Kotlin.**
You forgot to mention Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where you cannot extends the base class, another technique would be making a wrapper class, and delegating all the methods to the base class. This works good in this case because the base class is implementing a base interface:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class WrappedMessage implements IMessage {
    private final IMessage message;

    public WrappedMessage(IMessage message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { // TODO add your own implementation
        return 4; // chosen by fair dice roll.
                  // guaranteed to be random.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { // TODO add your own implementation
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Delegate all other methods:

    @Override
    public IMessage createCopy() {
        // this method is special as it returns an IMessage,
        // make sure to give back our wrapper instead
        return new WrappedMessage(message.createCopy());
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        return message.getBody();
    }

    @Override
    public void setBody(byte[] body) {
        message.setBody(body);
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return message.getContentType();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        message.setContentType(contentType);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCorrelationId() {
        return message.getCorrelationId();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCorrelationId(String correlationId) {
        message.setCorrelationId(correlationId);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDeadLetterSource() {
        return message.getDeadLetterSource();
    }

    @Override
    public long getDeliveryCount() {
        return message.getDeliveryCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Instant getEnqueuedTimeUtc() {
        return message.getEnqueuedTimeUtc();
    }

    @Override
    public Instant getExpiresAtUtc() {
        return message.getExpiresAtUtc();
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return message.getLabel();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        message.setLabel(label);
    }

    @Override
    public UUID getLockToken() {
        return message.getLockToken();
    }

    @Override
    public Instant getLockedUntilUtc() {
        return message.getLockedUntilUtc();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLockedUntilUtc(Instant lockedUntilUtc) {
        message.setLockedUntilUtc(lockedUntilUtc);
    }

    @Override
    public MessageBody getMessageBody() {
        return message.getMessageBody();
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessageBody(MessageBody body) {
        message.setMessageBody(body);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessageId() {
        return message.getMessageId();
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        message.setMessageId(messageId);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPartitionKey() {
        return message.getPartitionKey();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPartitionKey(String partitionKey) {
        message.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return message.getProperties();
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperties(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        message.setProperties(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public String getReplyTo() {
        return message.getReplyTo();
    }

    @Override
    public void setReplyTo(String replyTo) {
        message.setReplyTo(replyTo);
    }

    @Override
    public String getReplyToSessionId() {
        return message.getReplyToSessionId();
    }

    @Override
    public void setReplyToSessionId(String replyToSessionId) {
        message.setReplyToSessionId(replyToSessionId);
    }

    @Override
    public Instant getScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc() {
        return message.getScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc();
    }

    @Override
    public void setScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc(Instant scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc) {
        message.setScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc(scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc);
    }

    @Override
    public Instant getScheduledEnqueuedTimeUtc() {
        return message.getScheduledEnqueuedTimeUtc();
    }

    @Override
    public void setScheduledEnqueuedTimeUtc(Instant scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc) {
        message.setScheduledEnqueuedTimeUtc(scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSequenceNumber() {
        return message.getSequenceNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public String getSessionId() {
        return message.getSessionId();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
        message.setSessionId(sessionId);
    }

    @Override
    public Duration getTimeToLive() {
        return message.getTimeToLive();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTimeToLive(Duration timeToLive) {
        message.setTimeToLive(timeToLive);
    }

    @Override
    public String getTo() {
        return message.getTo();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTo(String to) {
        message.setTo(to);
    }

    @Override
    public String getViaPartitionKey() {
        return message.getViaPartitionKey();
    }

    @Override
    public void setViaPartitionKey(String partitionKey) {
        message.setViaPartitionKey(partitionKey);
    }
}
```